# what kind of certificate? how to get rid of it?

Tags: windows, outlook, windows-10, certificate, rdp

When connected to a remote desktop, a certificate is generated on the remote with the name "S-1-5-21-183##3189-3615##5645-3821##652-1001/b73cf###-e0cb-414####ea-ab21ffa8a2b2/login.windows.net/c1c942f3-2##49af-98b4-5f34bba3c5df/y.k###kov@so##.ru"(some symbols are replaced with grids), valid until 2048 and assignment" Log in smart card. " Locally this is contained in Certificates / Personal and Certificates / Local NonRemovable. What is this sert? And how to make it not generated remotely?

Comment: Where is the remote certificate located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the RDP connection settings, select Local resources - Details, and uncheck "Smart cards"